# Edit View of Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm new at Sharepoint Designer 2010. 
I want to make border for announcement web part at Tag Properties/style  but nothing change. I changed the color and width of border but the changes don't seem. How can I make border view? 
Thank you.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs0" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.WebUI" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"       %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use css. Open SPD 2010 and then open the webpart. click advanced mode. Within the PlaceHolderHead portion add your relative css paths. It would be good to make a local document library on the same site to hold all of your scripts and css files.

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../StyleLibrary/CSS/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../StyleLibrary/JS/jquery- 1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../StyleLibrary/JS/jquery- ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#hometab" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true
    });
$("#hometab").accordion().css("float","left");
$("#hometab").accordion().css("margin","10px");
$("#hometab").accordion().css("width","700px");
});
    </script>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
</ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
```

Once you do this you can reference the class within the PlaceHolderMain ContentPlaceHolder. Just make sure that you style the table

EDIT:

Here are the references you need

```
    <%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
```